# How do I clean stains from rice pilaf from my off-white carpet and wall?

Tags: walls, cleaning, carpet

I spilled rice pilaf on my carpet and I don't know how to clean the stains it left. I picked up most of it, but as you can see, remnants of it still persist. It has now been sitting for about a day. Is there a DIY way to totally remove it?

[image]

Comment: What was in the pilaf? That would help suggest the type of cleaner to use, though for a food stain I would probably start with an oxygen based cleaner.

Comment: You probably need the *Rice Pilaf Forum* or the *Stain Mogul Database*.

Answer (score 1):

The method of cleaning will depend on what your carpet is made of.  Synthetic carpet (nylon)  -   and wool or wool blend carpet generally require different chemicals.  Wool responds well to slightly acidic condition based cleaners - a home made one being - approx 300mls (1 and a bit cups) of warm water, 1 teaspoon white vinegar and 1 drop of dish washing detergent.  mix well and dab on stain. Treating stain whilst still damp gives better chance of removal than when stain has dried out. Apply on a small patch of inconspicuos area first.  Dab dry with a towel.I worked as a wool technologist for 20 years and this was the most useful general method we used.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for nylon?